# Logs not printed in weblogic linux

Tags: linux, weblogic12c

We can able to configure -Dweblogic.Stdout and -Dweblogic.StdErr params in weblogic configuration to print logs

**Windows platform :**

> set SAVE_JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Xms8192m -Xmx10240m
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -Djavax.xml.soap.MessageFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl
>   -Dweblogic.Stdout="D:\ims_ecs\bea10_36\user_projects\domains\Domainname\logs\SystemOut.txt"
>   -Dweblogic.Stderr="D:\ims_ecs\bea10_36\user_projects\domains\Domainname\logs\SystemErr.txt"
>   -Dweblogic.slc=true -Dweblogic.debug.DebugServerLifeCycle=true
>
> Logs are printed in declared location .

**Linux platform :**

> set SAVE_JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Xms512m -Xmx1024m
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false -Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
>   -Dweblogic.Stdout=/u01/app/oracle/product/ofm12.1.2/user_projects/domains/Domainname/logs/SystemOut.txt
>   -Dweblogic.Stderr=/u01/app/oracle/product/ofm12.1.2/user_projects/domains/Domainname/logs/SystemErr.txt
>
> Able to start weblogic but logs not printed in Required location

*Can you please suggest how to get weblogic domain logs in linux*

Answer (score 1):

Windows and Linux have different nomenclature for their scripts.

Check `startWebLogic.sh` from WLS installation:

`${VARIABLE_NAME}` instead `%VARIABLE_NAME%`

`:` instead `;`
etc.

Snippet code from it:

```
JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dweblogic.management.password=${WLS_PW}"

...
...

${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java ${JAVA_VM} ${MEM_ARGS} -Dweblogic.Name=${SERVER_NAME} -Djava.security.policy=${WLS_POLICY_FILE} ${JAVA_OPTIONS} ${PROXY_SETTINGS} ${SERVER_CLASS}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Devwebcl. Instead of % symbol need to use {} in linux

then logs get printed .

used command in linux :

SAVE_JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Djavax.xml.soap.MessageFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl -Dweblogic.Stdout="/u01/app/oracle/product/ofm12.1.2/user_projects/domains/domainname/logs/SystemOut.txt" -Dweblogic.Stderr="/u01/app/oracle/product/ofm12.1.2/user_projects/domains/domainname/logs/SystemErr.txt"-Dweblogic.slc=true -Dweblogic.debug.DebugServerLifeCycle=true -Dweblogic.log.RedirectstdoutToServerLogEnabled=true